# Prove $\frac1{\sin A}+\frac1{\sin B}+\frac1{\sin C}-\frac12(\tan\frac{A}{2}+\tan\frac{B}{2}+\tan\frac{C}{2}) \ge \sqrt{3}$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $ABC$ be a triangle. Prove that: $$\frac{1}{\sin A}+\frac{1}{\sin B}+\frac{1}{\sin C}-\frac{1}{2}\left(\tan\frac{A}{2}+\tan\frac{B}{2}+\tan\frac{C}{2}\right) \ge \sqrt{3} $$
My attempt:
$$P=\frac{1}{\sin A}+\frac{1}{\sin B}+\frac{1}{\sin C}-\frac{1}{2}\left(\tan\frac{A}{2}+\tan\frac{B}{2}+\tan\frac{C}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\cot\frac{A}{2}+\cot\frac{B}{2}+\cot\frac{C}{2}\right)$$
$$\alpha = \cot\frac{A}{2}+\cot\frac{B}{2}+\cot\frac{C}{2}=\cot\frac{A}{2}\cdot\cot\frac{B}{2}\cdot\cot\frac{C}{2}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \alpha \ge3.\sqrt[3]{\alpha} \Leftrightarrow \alpha^2\ge27\Leftrightarrow \alpha\ge3\sqrt{3}$$
$$\Rightarrow P=\frac{1}{2}\alpha\ge\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
Hmm where I was wrong ?

Comment: Use \ before writing a trig. function so that $cos(x)$ becomes $\cos(x)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not wrong because
$$
\frac32\sqrt{3}\ge \sqrt3.
$$

You just have proved a stronger inequality than required.

Answer (score 3):

Let $p$ is the semi-perimeter, $R$ is circumradius and $r$ is radius.

We have
$$\frac{1}{\sin A}+\frac{1}{\sin B}+\frac{1}{\sin C} = \frac{2R}{a} + \frac{2R}{b} + \frac{2R}{c} = \frac{4R+r}{2p}+\frac{p}{2r},$$
and
$$\tan\frac{A}{2}+\tan\frac{B}{2}+\tan\frac{C}{2} = \sum \frac{r}{b+c-a} = \frac{4R+r}{p}.$$
The inequality become
$$p \geqslant 2\sqrt3 r.$$
Which is true by know inequality $$p \geqslant 3\sqrt 3 r.$$